# Graphical details of changing functions

Tags: analytic-geometry

I'm struggeling a bit with the transformations of a function when values are changed (for instance an offset to the right etc).

So far I have found the following:
http://www.drcruzan.com/Images/TransformationEquation.png

Are there more transformations that I should look into? Any recommended sites, where aI can see them graphically?

Comment: what is the effect when I have a function f(x) = x^2 and then change it to: f(x+3) whats the value then?

Comment: A good idea is to look at Geogebra and have a play with the slide bars.

Comment: @Karl Yes I played around with https://www.desmos.com/ , however I'm not sure if I have covered all the possibilites. For instance I haven't found what addin a number in the function (like my first comment) actually does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest transformations of the graph $y=f(x)$ are these:

$y=f(x+a)$ moves $a$ units in the *negative* $x$ direction

$y=f(x)+a$ moves $a$ units in the *positive* $y$ direction

$y=f(ax)$ scales by a factor $1/a$ about the $y$-axis

$y=af(x)$ scales by a factor $a$ about the $x$-axis

$y=f(-x)$ reflects about the $y$-axis

$y=-f(x)$ reflects about the $x$-axis

$y=f^{-1}(x)$ reflects about the line $y=x$ (if the inverse exists)

$y=\left|f(x)\right|$ reflects the negative parts of $f(x)$ about the $x$ axis

$y=f(\left|x\right|)$ reflects the half of the graph with negative $x$ about the $y$ axis

Comment: thanks a lot I didn't have the difference between a * f(x) and f(a*x) and the inverse